# Error when installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When installing SQL Server 2008 R2 from the command line prompt, I am getting the following error that is recorded in the Summary file.

```
Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101217_131444\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: System.ArgumentNullException
    Message: 
        Value cannot be null.
        Parameter name: path2
    Data: 
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPublic.RecomputeDirectoryPaths()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPublic.Calculate()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun)
```

Has anyone seen this.

Here is what I am sending for the command line parameters.

```
/q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="myPassword" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like paths to shared tools or data/logs are required by the setup, but I'd try specifying those.

If that doesn't work, I'd try using a [slipstream method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955392) to get the install going.

Maybe you found a bug which has been resolved.  And if you didn't get your syntax from a supplied MSFT sample, I'd try using some of their code as a test.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error.  I discovered that the INSTANCENAME command line parameter is required.

For reference, the setup installer exited with error code 1972126374.